# Extjs grid with CellEditing - event for changing of grid field DURING editing

Tags: events, extjs, datagrid, grid

I have a grid with editable fields (by means of CellEditung plugin).
I need to execute some function each time the content of a field of the grid is changing (I need it for a text field and for a combo box field).
Unfortunately I cannot use event 'edit' since it is fired only when edition process is finished (edited field goes out of focus), and I need capture text changing events (~= keyup event while editing text field).
Anybody knows a way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use cellclick event listener to get the record.

```
  cellclick:function( thisObj, td, cellIndex, record, tr, rowIndex, e, eOpts ){
        console.log(record);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

if you need to do something on selection change, you could wire to one of the methods in to the [gridSelectionModel](http://docs-origin.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.grid.CellSelectionModel-event-selectionchange)

also you could wire a function to [columnModel](http://docs-origin.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.grid.Column)

or just [cellclick](http://docs-origin.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.grid.GridPanel-event-cellclick) or [celldblclick](http://docs-origin.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.grid.GridPanel-event-celldblclick)